# Matplotlib plot no output jupyter-lab

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, backtrader

I know I am beating a dead horse here, but I simply can't get the matplotlib plot to display in a Jupyterlab notebook.

I am trying to run a python script that eventually plots inside a jupyter cell.

**Things I have tried:**

- The best success that I had was with the `%run` magic command: `%run pythonscript.py`. This then threw an error, but still was able to display a plot after it:

```
   /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in
   mpl_execfile(fname, *where, **kw)
       187         matplotlib.interactive(is_interactive)
       188         # make rendering call now, if the user tried to do it
   --> 189         if plt.draw_if_interactive.called:
       190             plt.draw()
       191             plt.draw_if_interactive.called = False
   
   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'called'
```

However this was short-lived as it then just showed the error with no plot after a kernel restart.

- `%matplotlib inline` `!python/!python3 pythonscript.py` No error. Nothing not even the `[[Figure 2D....]]
- `%matplotlib notebook` `!python/!python3 pythonscript.py` No error. Nothing not even the `[[Figure 2D....]]
- Without the `%matplotlib` magic command. No error. Nothing not even the `[[Figure 2D....]]
- `%run pythonscript.py`. We get the `AttributeError` as shown above.
- `%pylab inline` yields nothing if coupled with `!python pythonscript.py` and yields the `AttributeError` if with `%run`.
- `%matplotlib inline` `%run pythonscript.py`. We get the `AttributeError` as shown above.

Trying to learn more about the attribute error when running the magic command yielded deadends.

pip list:

```
ipympl                        0.7.0
ipython                       7.27.0
jupyterlab                    3.1.10
ipykernel                     6.4.1
ipywidgets                    7.6.4
jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.1
matplotlib                    3.2.2
prompt-toolkit                3.0.20
```

At this point, I think I have exhausted most resources. Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit: Request screenshots and code explanation:

The code is based off of BackTrader, a backtesting library. The line of code that does the plotting is `cerebro.plot()`. Docs: https://www.backtrader.com/docu/plotting/plotting/

[image: Full AttributeError Stacktrace]

Comment: Would be great if you could include screenshots and the code

Comment: @Luke Updated post to include more information.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code or the `.ipynb` so I can try?

Comment: As I was creating the gist to share with you, I stumbled across 2 lines at the top of `pythonscript.py`: `import matplotlib matplotlib.use("agg")`. Huge face palm and I feel extremely silly after removing those 2 lines. Plot was finally able to display after `%matplotlib inline %run pythonscript.py`. Even kernel restarted to double check. You inadvertently gave me the solution lol. Thank you!

Comment: Lol ;) Anytime!